# Given an array of structs, how to pass all the values for one member of the struct to a function

Tags: c

Given an array of structs, is there a way to pass

```
emp[0].hourly_wage, emp[1].hourly_wage, emp[2].hourly_wage, emp[3].hourly_wage, emp[4].hourly_wage
```

to a function as an array of floats?

Is it possible to pass an array of floats containing only the "hourly_wage" member and not the "OT" member... without just copying the values into a separate array of floats and then passing it to the function.

```
struct employee
{
    float hourly_wage;
    float OT;
};

struct employee emp[5];
```

Comment: You either create the array and pass it, or you create a function that takes a `struct employee` (or pointer to it) and loop over your array of struct processing each `hourly_wage` that way. No way to magically pass an array of one member of an array of struct otherwise. Passing a pointer is the most efficient, though in your case, conceivably your struct would be the same size as a pointer on x86_64.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot but you can create another array of *pointers* pointing to that one member in the array of structure and pass this array of pointers to function.

Implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
#define ARR_SZ 5

struct employee
{
        float hourly_wage;
        float OT;
};

void test_fun(float **arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SZ; ++i) {
                printf ("%f ", *arr[i]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
}

int main(void) {
        struct employee emp[ARR_SZ];

        for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SZ; ++i) {
                emp[i].hourly_wage = 2.0f;  // dummy value
                emp[i].OT = 1.0f;    // dummy value
        }

        float *hw_arr[ARR_SZ];

        for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SZ; ++i) {
                hw_arr[i] = &(emp[i].hourly_wage);
        }

        test_fun(hw_arr);

        return 0;
}
```

Or simply pass the array of structure to the function and access that member:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
#define ARR_SZ 5

struct employee
{
        float hourly_wage;
        float OT;
};

void test_fun(struct employee *arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SZ; ++i) {
                printf ("%f ", arr[i].hourly_wage);
        }
        printf ("\n");
}

int main(void) {
        struct employee emp[ARR_SZ];

        for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SZ; ++i) {
                emp[i].hourly_wage = 2.0f;  // dummy value
                emp[i].OT = 1.0f;    // dummy value
        }

        test_fun(emp);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

The closest might be:

```
float a[10];
memcpy(a, emp, sizeof(a));
```

Or:

```
void foo(float *a) { ... }
foo((float *) emp);
```

But that is probably undefined behaviour as it relies on there being no packing at the end of each `struct` (probably none in this case, but not universally true - see [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31082389/1270789)), and anyway gives the data in the wrong order for you.

Comment: Oooh I bet you like playing *Russian Roulette* too `:)` The first two-character sentence captures it all.

Answer (score 0):

It's no possible.

An array requires that the array elements are located in consecutive memory (note: there may be padding between members but that's not relevant here).

In your case the memory layout of `emp` is like:

```
addrX (i.e. emp)         :  float // emp[0].hourly_wage
addrX + 1 * sizeof(float):  float // emp[0].OT
addrX + 2 * sizeof(float):  float // emp[1].hourly_wage
addrX + 3 * sizeof(float):  float // emp[1].OT
addrX + 4 * sizeof(float):  float // emp[2].hourly_wage
addrX + 5 * sizeof(float):  float // emp[2].OT
...
```

and there is no way to turn that into

```
addrY                    :  float // emp[0].hourly_wage
addrY + 1 * sizeof(float):  float // emp[1].hourly_wage
addrY + 2 * sizeof(float):  float // emp[2].hourly_wage
...
```

without copying from the first array to another array.

Instead the normal thing to do, is to pass the whole array of struct, i.e. pass a `struct employee` **pointer** and access whatever you need from the struct.